# A good way for programming Android and IOS Apps?

Tags: jquery, android, ios, mobile

I wonder what is a good way to program them both at the same time. I have tried Phonegap, but I have serious issues with draggable and resizable objects. What is the best way you would advice for making apps for both of those platforms without having the rewrite codes? What I for example try to achieve is placing objects on a picture and then make the objects draggable and resizable (by using two fingers just like how you would enlarge a webpage and make it smaller). If you have any suggestions please do throw them this way since im eager to learn :)

Thanks!

Comment: You want HTML5 based applications? Or what programming languages are you willing to use?

Comment: HTML 5 and such could be handy yes. So if I would choose phonegap. Which technique would work well for dragable resizable in the way I described? Since my touch doesn't seem to react at all.

Comment: You should also determine / experiment with, how much 'lagginess' would your users be willing to tolerate for non-native apps. While HTML5 / JS is great for cross-platform apps, the responsiveness is yet to reach Native levels, and it may / maynot be applicable to your app, but you should try to find it out.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not a populair solution, but you could take a look at flash/as3.
Adobe has a tool that enables you to export to android/iphone native packages.

as long as you don't do any heavy graphics stuff it will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to write each app for each platform but often that isn't realistically possible

There are alternatives to PhoneGap like Appcelerator which actually converts your code into native Objective C/Java, I suggest trying these platforms out until you find one that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! What would you personally suggest? Out of those two I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could try HTML5 and javascript, though you'll need a bit of separate code for both devices to 'read' the HTML.

Comment: HTML 5 and such could be handy yes. So if I would choose phonegap. Which technique would work well for dragable resizable in the way I described? Since my touch doesn't seem to react at all.

Comment: If your using HTML, you can use javascript to resize the objects